# Best approach to smooth pathfinding for 2d top down game LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection, ai, path-finding

I'm trying to make a buddy ai that follows the player (being controlled by you) around and at the moment it works but when I add collision detection it doesn't work very well when the buddy hits an obstacle. I was just wondering what would be the best approach (like perhaps an implementation of the a* algorithm) to making the ai movement smooth and so it avoids obstacles?
Here is the update method currently for my buddy class:

```
public void update() {

    setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());

    float xDiff = Math.abs(player.getX() - getX());
    float yDiff = Math.abs(player.getY() - getY());

    if (player.getX() > getX() && xDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setX(getX()+speed);
    }
    else if (player.getX() < getX() && xDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setX(getX()-speed);
    }

    if (player.getY() > getY() && yDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setY(getY()+speed);
    }
    else if (player.getY() < getY() && yDiff > buddyDistance) {
        setY(getY()-speed);
    }

}
```

Comment: There are lots of solutions but A\* is the most common

Comment: Try looking into steering behaviors. It is not path finding in the sense of precomputing a route. It's more like telling object A to pursue object B, and avoid any obstacles while you are at it. I did a quick search and found this link. I only gave it a quick glance, but I looks like enough to get you started. https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/series/understanding-steering-behaviors--gamedev-12732